# Historical Items Removal Policy

Tags: azure-pipelines

I want to store my builds and their artifacts online on `Azure-Pipelines`.

However, I cannot find how long before `AzureDevOps` deletes them.

How long does it take until `AzureDevOps` deletes them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for the retention policy on your build pipeline? You can find that if you edit your pipeline and select the Retention tab. Default is 10 builds stored for 30 days.